# StageWebView - hide just for JS

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to use StageWebView just for communicating with a JS page, without actually showing it at all

Is this possible, and if so, what is the best recommended way of doing it?

Seems that not setting the viewport might accomplish this, as well as positioning the viewport offscreen

Answer (score 1):

First you need the interaction, then you need to put the view off the stage. Take a look at RichWebView which is an alternative to StageWebView https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, you can't do this with [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html).

> The StageWebView class provides a simple means to display HTML content
>   on devices where the HTMLLoader class is not supported. The class
>   provides no interaction between ActionScript and the HTML content
>   except through the methods and properties of the StageWebView class
>   itself. **There is, for example, no way to pass values or call
>   functions between ActionScript and JavaScript.**

Using [HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html) you could do this.

Comment: There are hacks to allow JS<->AS... my question is more about hiding the view of StageWebView while it still processes things